# if condition using sympy equation solver/ sympy very slow

Tags: python, list, numpy, sympy

I want to solve this equation witht the following parameters:

```
gamma = 0.1
F = 0.5
w = 0
A = symbols('A')

a = 1 + w**4 -w**2 + 4*(gamma**2)*w**2
b = 1 - w**2

sol = solve(a*A**2 + (9/16)*A**6 + (3/2)*b*A**4 -F**2)

list_A = []
for i in range(len(sol)):
    if(type( solutions[i] )==float ):
        print(sol[i])
        list_A = sol[i]
```

However, as supposed, I am getting some real and complex values, and I want to remove the complex ones and only keep the floats. But this condition I implemented is not valid due to the type of sol[i] is either `sympy.core.add.Add` for complex or `sympy.core.numbers.Float` for floats.
My question is, how can I modify my condition so that it works for getting only the float values?
In addition, is there a way to speed it up? it is very slow if I put it in a loop for many values of omega.
this is my first time working with `sympy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it is able to validate solutions relative to assumptions on symbols, it will; so if you tell SymPy that `A` is real then -- if it can verify the solutions -- it will only show the real ones:

```
>>> A = symbols('A',real=True)
>>> sol = solve(a*A**2 + (9/16)*A**6 + (3/2)*b*A**4 -F**2)
>>> sol
[-0.437286658108243, 0.437286658108243]
```